# Sleep mode not working on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, suspend

My Asus doesn't go to sleep mode if I ask it to on Ubuntu 14.04. Sometimes it works after some updates, then it stops working after another update...

This is the message I get on a black screen for 3 seconds when I try to put it on sleep :
"Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected"